# PHP CURL Class does not accept object parameters

Tags: php, class, curl, php-curl

I have a class for curl queries. Authorizes on a closed page using the POST method, stores a cookie, and then makes a request GET receives an array of data. The class is designed to increase query performance and reduce time. That is, we make one connection and pass two requests GET and POST.

```
class Par {


    private $url;
    private $ch;

    public function __construct($print = false){
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        if (!$print){
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true) ;
        }
    }
    public function set($name, $value){
        curl_setopt($this->ch, $name, $value);
        return $this;
    }

    public function exec($url){
        curl_setopt($this->ch,  CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        return curl_exec($this->ch);
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        curl_close($this->ch);
    }
}
```

Next, I will create an object of class in which I set the parameters set. And I get access to the authorized page

```
$url_auth = 'http://site=user_login';
$url = 'http://site_search&group=1';

$auth_data = array(
    "login" => "login",
    "password" => "pas",
   
);

$parser = new Par();
$parser->set(CURLOPT_POST, true)
       ->set(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($auth_data))
      ->set(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
       ->set(CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__ .'/cook.txt')
       ->set(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ .'/cook.txt');
    
$data = $parser->exec($url_auth);
print_r($data);

$parser->set(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET')
       ->set(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ .'/cook.txt');

$data = $parser->exec($url);
print_r($data);
```

This code executes a POST request. When I want to set the Get option, I get nothing.
Where is the mistake? How to set parameters of object of a class so that two requests POST and GET were executed, and connection was only one.

Comment: I need to get data from $ url = 'http: // site_search & group = 1'; And the POST method is intended only for authorization and creation of cookies.

Comment: Do not use the same curl object again (for another request method).
EDIT: also check of curl errors.

Comment: How to solve this problem?